# Generic syntax symbol <~>

Tags: java, generics, ide

Working with IDE like NetBeans or IDEA, i've seen that they are converting generic types into this symbol:

```
private final List<String> ar = new ArrayList<~>();
```

But using this in a simple editor results in throwing an error. BTW Eclipse also doesn't like it. Is it somehow connected with type erasure mechanism?

Comment: Yes, thx. So this tilde is IDE specific?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will see that in IntelliJ its a different colour!

This is because it has used code folding to hide the code, but you can't write it this way in Java 6.

In Java 7 you can write

```
private final List<String> ar = new ArrayList<>();
```