# what does ~ mean in the java code?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does this tilde mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887876/what-does-this-tilde-mean)

I am using IntelliJ and found that it can re-factor my code of the following

```
Handle<String> handle = new Handler<String>() {}
```

to `Handler<String> handler = new Handler<~>() {}`

what's the meaning of ~ in the above?

Comment: I guess this is a shortcut to "infer please"

Comment: are you sure it didnt just fold the duplicate generics declaration for a nicer result?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4887876/what-does-this-tilde-mean and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915280/generic-syntax-symbol. Possible duplicates - voting to close.

Comment: IntelliJ calls this feature ["Automated code folding"](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_editor.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is a folding of the type arguments used by IntelliJ IDEA. It is a shorthand syntax for your viewing pleasure, not valid Java syntax.

Comment: Now this I can upvote :-) even though just closing the question as duplicate would have been better.

Comment: @JanDvorak Closing as dup would have been better, true. 'Twas a gut response.

Answer (score 1):

In Java `Handler handler = new Handler<~>() {}` means syntax error, nothing else

Comment: Even in Java 1.7? IntelliJ wouldn't recommend a syntax error.

Comment: @JanDvorak In Java 7 you write `<>`, not `<~>`.

Comment: As per the duplicate this seems like a IntelliJ-specific syntax that IntelliJ translates to valid java behind the scenes.

Comment: Technically correct but not a useful answer. -1

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler<String> handler = new Handler<~>() {};
```

will not compile it has no meaning (except for eye-catching effect).

`~` is Unary operator and it means Binary Ones Complement Operator it has the effect of 'flipping' bits.     (~A ) will give -60 which is 1100 0011

**EDIT**

According to @Jan Dvorak, The question is incorrect in stating the IDE suggested this as a refactor.

Comment: Technically correct but not a useful answer. -1; see the duplicate

Comment: what do you mean by useful?

Comment: The tilde is not actually present in the source code so no syntax error happens.

Comment: Now read the question carefully and if you feel strange afterwards, feel free to take back your downvote :)

Comment: The question is incorrect in stating the IDE suggested this as a refactor. Would you mind debunking that in your answer?

Comment: Note this is technically not refactoring, but code folding.

Comment: I disagree with "put the correct value after refactoring"... refactoring is the act of changing the source code without changing its effect. What you mean code unfolding (which _technically_ doesn't happen, again).

Comment: ok, agreed I'll remove the refactoring part.